# How to translateX and translateY for an element other than a canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I want to translate a div element using javascript. I tried multiple ways, listed below (item is the element):

```js
item = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var x, y
x = y = 20
// doesn't change anything
item.style.translate = "translate(" + x + "px," + y + "px)";
// only works on canvas
try {
  item.translate(x, y);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

```html
<div id=myDiv>Text...</div>
```

How can I move the div without resorting to CSS (I want to do this to multiple elements, differently)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- add `var` keyword to `item`
- separate `x` and `y` assigning values
- replace `translate` with `transform`
- delete the colon `:` after `translate:()`

*NOTE:* add semicolons `;` to the code

```js
var item = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var x, y;
x = 60; y = 60;

item.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;
```

```html
<div id=myDiv>Text...</div>
```

To use the same functionality, create a `function` and pass:

```
// item, 50, 60 === el, x, y
addSpace(item, 50, 60);
```

**The Code**

```js
var item = document.getElementById("myDiv");

const addSpace = (el, x, y) => {
    return el.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;
};

addSpace(item, 60, 60);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Text</div>
```

Comment: What question update?  Without an edit history, it didn't happen.

Comment: Sorry my fault, I didn't notice the text part after the code in your question and thought it was an update.